# How to restart Docker Desktop after shutting down WSL?

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, minikube

I installed Docker Desktop for Win10 Home. Everything went fine and I was able to start up minikube.
Later I decided to stop `Vmmem.exe` because I wanted to play a game.
Ran the following command:

```
wsl --shutdown
```

Now `Vmmem.exe` has stopped running but how do I restart it?

`minikube start` gives the following error

```
* minikube v1.22.0 on Microsoft Windows 10 Home Single Language 10.0.19041 Build 19041
* Using the docker driver based on existing profile

X Exiting due to PROVIDER_DOCKER_VERSION_EXIT_1: "docker version --format -" exit status 1: error during connect: In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run with elevated privileges to connect.: Get "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/version": open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.
* Documentation: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/docker/
```

`wsl -l -v` gives following

```
  NAME                   STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu-20.04           Stopped         2
  docker-desktop-data    Stopped         2
  docker-desktop         Stopped         2
```

What am I missing here? Any help is much appreciated

Comment: If Docker Desktop isn't running, just run it in Windows (from the Start Menu).  It will create a task-bar icon when running.  If it is running, try the "Troubleshoot" icon (picture of a bug) and use "Restart Docker Desktop".  That should work for you, and Docker Desktop will bring up the two `docker-desktop.*` WSL instances.  Assuming that does what you need, I can copy this into an answer.

Answer (score 27):

1. Open Docker Desktop
2. Click 'Troubleshooting' icon in top bar (between settings and sign in)
3. Click 'Restart' (first option)

Now docker is restarted and you'll have it enabled in your wsl

Comment: this just closed Docker for me and didn't restart it but when I manually started Docker afterward it worked as expected

Comment: It is now named as "Reset Kubernetes" button

Answer (score -1):

Steps to run install and run docker daemon on WSL2

Installation steps:

```
1. Add the stable channel repository and upadte run below commad:

   sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
   sudo apt-get update -y

2.Install the latest Docker CE
  sudo apt-get install -y docker-ce

3.Add user to docker group to run docker using non root user.
  sudo usermod -aG docker $USER && newgrp docker

4. Run docker daemon:
   sudo dockerd

Optional steps:

5. Configure Docker to start on boot
    sudo systemctl enable docker.service
    sudo systemctl enable containerd.service
   

    TO disable this use below command:
    
    
    sudo systemctl disable docker.service
    sudo systemctl disable containerd.service
```

Comment: I get the following message when trying to use systemctl: `System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.`

Comment: Alternatively you can use this command to start docker : sudo service docker start  in wsl2

Comment: @rubalvjaiswal, I believe WSL does not have systemd - these command will not work.